# Laravel 5.6 auth - not standard table

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

I quite new to Laravel and have some problems with using **auth** option.
I'm trying to use auth on another custom table. I've setup the connection to new table already however Laravel is still searching the email field. In my table there is 'login' field instead. I don't know where to change it, anyone could help?

I'm using Laravel 5.6
I've created new Model and added protected `$table` to **User** (default) model.

that's my error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'email' in 'where clause'

Comment: hey share your code please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create this function in your `loginController`

```php
public function login(LoginRequest $request)
{

    $user = User::select('id')->where('user_name', $request->user_name)->where('pin', $request->pin)->first();

    if ($user) {
        Auth::loginUsingId($user->id);
        return redirect()->intended('/dashboard');
    } else {
        return redirect()->back()->with('app_warning', 'Credenciales Invalidas!')->withInput();
    }

}
```

change this `user->name and pin` for your field on `database`

Answer (score 0):

You can override any function in the file `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php`. In your case you could do by just adding this to `app/Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php`

```
public function username()
{
    return 'login';
}
```

Have a look at the other functions in the `AuthenticatesUsers.php`. Each of them you can override. But don't override files in the vendors folder. Whatever you change will one day be overwritten after a `composer update`.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.

If you check the Laravel docs for Authentication there is a section named "Authentication Quickstart" with a subsection named "Authentication -> Username Customization". This shows the method on the `LoginController` you would need to define to adjust the field used as the username, `email` by default.

```php
public function username()
{
    return 'login';
}
```

[Laravel 5.6 Docs - Authentication - Authentication Quickstart](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authentication#authentication-quickstart)